# Quality assessment of 2 quantile regression methods

Tags: r, cross-validation, quantile-regression

**1. Context**

I have a dataset structured like this:

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   52135 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ lat          : num  59 59 55 59 59 63 59 59 59 59 ...
 $ long         : num  16 16 12 16 16 14 15 16 15 15 ...
 $ date         : chr  "1951-03-22" "1951-04-08" "1952-02-03" "1952-03-08" ...
 $ julian_day   : num  81 98 34 68 53 71 16 37 73 87 ...
 $ year         : int  1951 1951 1952 1952 1953 1953 1954 1954 1954 1954 ...
 $ decade       : chr  "1950-1959" "1950-1959" "1950-1959" "1950-1959" ...
 $ time         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lat_grouped  : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year_centered: 'AsIs' num  -35 -35 -34 -34 -33 -33 -32 -32 -32 -32 ...
```

I have performed two quantile regression methods on the 3 groups of latitudes (1, 2 and 3) in my data.

The first method is very common, using the `rq` function from the `quantreg` package.

The second is adapted from *Solution to the Non-Monotonicity and Crossing Problems in Quantile Regression* by Saleh & Saleh (https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.04805). From what I have understood (I am not a mathematician), the algorithm is based on a constrained optimization approach, where the quantile regression line is constrained to be non-crossing by imposing a set of linear constraints on the parameters of the regression line. These constraints are formulated as a set of linear inequalities, which are then solved using a linear programming algorithm.

The functions implemented given in the paper are these ones:

```
minimize.logcosh <- function(par, X, y, tau) {
  diff <- y-(X %*% par)
  check <- (tau-0.5)*diff+(0.5/0.7)*logcosh(0.7*diff)+0.4
  return(sum(check))
}

smrq <- function(X, y, tau){
  p = ncol(X)
  op.result <- optim(rep(0, p), fn = minimize.logcosh, method = 'BFGS', X = X, y = y, tau = tau)
  beta <- op.result$par
  return (beta)
}
```

The regression was performed for tau = 1:99 / 100.

**2. Results**

[image]

As you can see, visually, there is a clear difference between the 2 methods.

The `smrq` function from Saleh&Saleh (red, right column) *seems to* outperform `qr` traditional way of doing (blue, left column).

I have also plotted the intercepts, and as shown in Saleh&Saleh, smrq gets rid of the non-monotonic behaviour observed in rq:

[image]

However, I wanted confirmation that the `smrq` is better, so I performed a k-fold cross-validation. But here, `qr` seems to be much better than `smrq`.

[image]

**3. Issues**

I have in mind that the evaluation of a model is to correlate to your research question and that deciding which modelling approach is better is context-dependent.

However, the approach used by Saleh&Saleh is supposed to help deal with crossing problems.

As they state, their paper *"describes a unique and elegant solution to the problem based on a flexible check function that is easy to understand and implement in R and Python, while greatly reducing or even eliminating the crossing problem entirely. It will be very important in all areas where quantile regression is routinely used and may also find application in robust regression, especially in the context of machine learning."*

I must admit that I do not know where to go from all this. Some questions that I have in mind are:

- was the k-fold cross-validation relevant (why/why not)?
- any idea on a relevant way to test `rq` against `smrq` other than a visual approach?

I have tried to be concise and yet complete, which is not always easy. I would be happy to bring some more details if needed - please just ask.

Comment: Maybe could you try to model your quantile regressions with `qgam`, which could be a sort of arbiter between smrq and qr?